# Get Facebook wall feed

Tags: facebook, permissions, access-token, facebook-wall

1. Can you display a 'pages' wall feed 'without' having to get a access_token?
2. Is there anyway to display a 'pages' wall feed on a external website 'without' logging in the user?
3. Why do I have to create a Facebook Application set up to do any of this when my application is not connected in any way to the Facebook 'page'?
4. Why is it all so complicated?

Answer (score 2):

1. No, you need an access_token.
2. Yes, but you will need an access_token to pull the page's wall feed.
3. Because the sandbox belongs to facebook, and you have to play by their rules.
4. The more secure you make something, the more complicated it gets.  Just one of the laws of API design.